# Bean works only when it is injected as a method paramater

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, resttemplate

I'm working on a client application that uses RestTemplate for communicating with a REST API.

RestTemplate is configured this way:

```
@Configuration
class RestTemplateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun restTemplate(restTemplateBuilder: RestTemplateBuilder): RestTemplate {
        return restTemplateBuilder.build()
    }
}
```

But I also tried configuring it like that already:

```
@Configuration
class RestTemplateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun restTemplate(restTemplateBuilder: RestTemplateBuilder): RestTemplate {
        val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
        val converter = MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter ()
        converter.objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
        restTemplate.messageConverters.add(converter)
        return restTemplate
    }
}
```

So, when the bean is inject as a method parameter, just for test purposes, it works fine:

```
@GetMapping
fun getAll(restTemplate: RestTemplate, model: Model): String {
    val response = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/api/metagame/archetypes", HttpMethod.GET, null,
            object : TypeReferences.PagedModelType<ArchetypeModel>() {})

    val archetypes = response.body?.content ?: ArrayList<EntityModel<ArchetypeModel>>()

    model.addAttribute("archetypes", archetypes)

    return "metagame/archetypes/index"
}
```

But, every time it is injected as a constructor parameter the response comes empty:

```
class ArchetypeController(val restTemplate: RestTemplate)
```

Is it a Kotlin issue or a configuration problem...? Since Spring isn't giving me any error message I'm totally lost :/

Comment: can you please show your entire ArchetypeController, remember you can only constructor inject beans into classes that are lifecycle controlled by spring.

Comment: Why not inject RestTemplate into your controller as a local variable with `@Autowired`?

Comment: @BankBuilder because if you want to unit test, you can instantiate the class yourself and pass a RestTemplate through the constructor. And also spring themselves favour constructor injection over field injection.

Comment: @Thomas Andolf ArchetypeController is a RestController for the ArchetypeModel sorry I forget to copy the line containing that annotation. And it’s method, getAll, is above it in my text.

Comment: Check out the whole code in my repository https://github.com/estevaodias/metagame

Comment: add the code in the question, people are not supposed to look for the code. We want to have reproducible examples here.

Comment: @Thomas Andolf you don’t have to search for anything. But if you want to reproduce this scenario and find what is wrong, even if you’ve never faced this error, all information  you’ll need is here.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html